# C++ vector insert implementation crash

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I'm trying to reproduce the behavior of vector and a weird crash occurs when I try to use `vector::insert(iterator, size_type, const T &)`, my code looks like this:

```c
iterator    insert(iterator pos, size_type count, const T &value) {
    return _M_insert_size(pos, count, value);
}

//with
iterator    _M_insert_size(iterator pos, size_type count, const T &value) {
    const size_type size = _size + count; // get the new size

    if (_capacity < size) reserve(size); // reserve if larger than capacity
    // here `end()` is still using old size
    std::copy(pos, end(), pos + count); // move [pos;end()[ to (pos + count)
    std::fill(pos, pos + count, value); // fill [pos;(pos + count)[ with value
    _size = size; // set the new size
    return pos;
}

//and
void        reserve(size_type new_cap) {
    if (new_cap > max_size()) throw std::length_error(std::string("vector::") + __func__);

    if (new_cap > _capacity) {
        T   *ptr = _allocator.allocate(new_cap);
        std::copy(begin(), end(), ptr);
        _allocator.deallocate(_array, _capacity);
        _capacity = new_cap;
        _array = ptr;
    }
}

//and
iterator                begin(void) { return _array; }
iterator                end(void) { return _array + _size; }
```

My code seems legit but I get this crash

```
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
[1]    3440 abort (core dumped)  ./build/test
```

and with valgrind I get an invalid read at `std::copy`, but I struggled for the past four hours but didn't find which value or parameter was wrong. The crash occured at this test:

```
            ft::vector< int >   v(10, 42);
            std::vector< int >  r(10, 42);

            v.insert(v.begin(), 5UL, 1);
            r.insert(r.begin(), 5UL, 1);
```

Comment: Notice how `reserve` invalidates iterators, including the one pointed to by `pos`.

Comment: Note that `allocate(new_cap)` does not start the lifetime of any of the arrays' elements. Using `std::copy` will try to assign to these uninitialized objects which is UB. You need to create actual objects in this storage first. You also fail to destroy the elements before you deallocating old storage. It's fine for `int` but it will be problematic with non-trivial types. See [`construct`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/construct) and [`destroy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/destroy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    if (_capacity < size) reserve(size); // reserve if larger than capacity
    // here `end()` is still using old size
    std::copy(pos, end(), pos + count); // move [pos;end()[ to (pos + count)
```

- If you're debugging this, you should *know* whether you called `reserve()` here, right? Because you're single-stepping through the function.

  - If you *didn't* already know this, that's something you should look out for when debugging. If you did, it should have been in the question.
- And since you're writing your own own [`std::vector::reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) you know it invalidated all iterators including `pos`, because your implementation always allocates new storage.

  - If you want to add a debug mode to detect this kind of stuff, you can add a generation counter to the container and to your iterator, and increment the container's generation counter on every invalidating operation.
- If you get an invalid read in valgrind, it should also tell you where the memory was originally allocated and where it was released.

  - If it didn't, check its options. If it did, that information should also be in the question.

So, the proximate fix is to write `const auto pos_offset = pos - begin();` before (maybe) calling `reserve()`, and then use `pos_offset` to recover the correct iterator.

Other issues are:

- identifiers with a leading underscore followed by an upper-case letter (like `_M`) are reserved for the implementation. The `std::vector` provided in your standard library is part of the implementation, but your code is not.
- `_allocator.deallocate` does not destroy the array elements, and `_allocator.allocate` does not construct them. See the use of `std::construct_at` and `std::destroy_n` in the [`std::allocator` example code](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/deallocate):

  ```
      S* s = allocator.allocate(n); // may throw
      for (std::size_t i{}; i != n; ++i) {
      //  allocator.construct(&s[i], i+42); // removed in C++20
          std::construct_at(&s[i], i+42);   // since C++20
      }
      std::destroy_n(s, n);
      // or loop over allocator.destroy(&s[i]); before C++17
      allocator.deallocate(s, n);
  ```

Comment: The way that you say that my implementation always allocates new storage makes me ask then how could we implement it without doing so using std::allocator_traits? As there is no `realloc` method. But thanks for your post, it answers the question. I'm too used to C x)

Comment: You could in principle choose to use `realloc` when `std::is_trivial_v<T> == true`, but otherwise the only option is something platform-specific like `mmap`.